# In django dockerization nginx does not listen on port 80 and cannot find static files even though it is in nginx container

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose

**`Docker-compose.yml`**

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - "web"
    volumes:
      - ./static_volume/:/home/app/web/staticfiles
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./pgdb:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - .env
  web:
    build: .
    command: gunicorn config.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - ./static_volume/:/app/staticfiles
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - celery
    env_file:
      - .env
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  celery:
    build: .
    command: celery -A config worker -l info
    depends_on:
      - redis
    env_file:
      - .env
volumes:
  static_volume:
  pgdb:
    external: false
```

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream hello_django {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://hello_django;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/app/web/staticfiles;
    }
}
```

**Dockerfile for nginx**

```
FROM nginx:1.21-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

[this is web and nginx container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4Ekm.png)

I'm trying to dockerize my Django project and have successfully managed to serve static files without configuring nginx within the container. However, after installing nginx, the static files are not found by nginx even though they exist in the nginx container. Additionally, the site only seems to work on the localhost:8000 port.My Operation system is Windows

Comment: I would suggest to check the error.log of nginx. Somewhere in your container that file is to be found. Might be a problem of permissions or lack of MIME-types. Your last sentence indicates that you are not "using" nginx at all. When you access Port 8000 instead of Port 80 you are addressing uwsgi directly and therefore bypassing nginx. Might even be the case that nginx is not even running. But check the error.log and access.log to get more info about your nginx performance/status

Comment: It was a problem with the computer. Everything worked normally when I try on another computer